# Most efficient way to prove basic set equality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Suppose you are asked to prove that $A \cap (B - C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$. What is the “best” way to go about doing so? Remark: the equality we are asked to prove is not really relevant; I just picked a random example from Chapter 1 of Munkres which can't be completed in a line or two.

I will provide two ways I would prove it. I would like feedback on which is best, with feedback (if any) on how to improve the best one. We can define the best to be the proof which, in your own opinion, has the optimal combination of satisfactory, brevity, logical leaps, and readability as well as elegance.

*Proof 1:* Let $x \in A \cap (B - C)$. Then $x \in a$ and $x \in B - C$, and by definition of set difference,  $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$. Observe that $A \cap C \subset C$, and since $x \not\in C$, it follows that $x \not\in A \cap C$. Therefore, $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ but $x \not\in A \cap C$. The set of $x$ which satisfy this is $(A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$.

Now Let $x \in (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$. Then $x \in A \cap B \Rightarrow x \in A$ and $x \in B$ and $x \not\in A \cap C$. This means that $x \not\in A$ or $x \not\in C$, but we know $x \in A$, so $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ bug $x \not\in C$. Therefore, $A \cap (B - C)$. Alternatively, we could also write this as $(A \cap B) - C$. Either way, the proof is done.

*Proof 2:*

\begin{align*}
A \cap (B - C) 
&= \{ x \mid x \in A ~\text{and}~ x \in (B - C) \}, \\
&= \{ x \mid x \in A ~\text{and}~ (x \in B ~\text{and}~ x \not\in C) \},  \\
&= \{ x \mid (x \in A ~\text{and}~ x \in B) ~\text{and}~ (x \in A ~\text{and}~ x \not\in C)\}, \\
&= \{ x \mid (x \in A ~\text{and}~ x \in B) ~\text{and}~ x \not\in C\}, \\
&= (A \cap B) - C.
\end{align*} Now notice that

\begin{align*}
(A \cap B) - (A \cap C) &= \{ x \mid (x \in A ~\text{and}~ x \in B) ~\text{and}~ x \not\in A \cap C \}, \\
&= \{ x \mid (x \in A ~\text{and}~ x \in B) ~\text{and}~ (x \not\in A ~\text{or}~ x \not\in C ) \}, \\
&= \{ x \mid (x \in A ~\text{and}~ x \in B) ~\text{and}~ x \not\in C \}, \\
&= (A \cap B)-C,
\end{align*}which is is equal to $A \cap (B - C)$ by the previous part.

Bonus question: which way would Munkres want?

Comment: I don't know which way the problem composer would prefer, or which way that a class teacher would prefer.  Personally, I would *advise* any Math student relatively new to the material to automatically opt for method 1.  The reason is that the general method of proving that set $S$ = set $T$ is to show that $S \subseteq T$ and that $T \subseteq S$.  Further, you show (for example) that $S \subseteq T$ by showing that $x \in S \implies x \in T.$  So, this is the very basic approach that I would want the new student to master.  That is, I would advise bypassing any attempt at *elegance*.

Comment: @user2661923 What about a not-so-new student?

Comment: Once you master method 1, it is probably a good idea to look for more elegant approaches.  Often, there are intermediate results that the student can/should strive to build on, so that the desired conclusion becomes a consequence of an intermediate result.  Also, by striving for elegance, you are reinforcing your underlying fluency in the *language* and also attempting to find hidden *concepts*.

Answer (score 1):

I think proof 1 is the better proof for the reasons described by user2661923. However, personally I like the logic based approach for these types of problems, as the proofs tend to be clear and short. I know some people don't like these (Why? Because they don't consider themselves to be computers!). To do them, you need to have a handle on the logic identities and how to generate them (e.g. through natural deduction). Here is the proof:

$x\in(A\cap B) \backslash  (A \cap C)$
$\iff ((x \in A \wedge x \in B) \wedge \neg(x \in A \wedge x \in C))$
$\iff ((x \in A \wedge x \in B) \wedge (x \notin A \lor x \notin C)) \hspace {35pt} $    By Demorgan
$\iff ((x \in A \wedge x \in B) \wedge  x \notin C) \hspace {79pt}$ Distributivity and eliminate contradiction
$\iff (x \in A \wedge (x \in B \wedge  x \notin C)) \hspace {79pt}$ By associativity
$\iff x \in A \cap ( B \backslash  C)$

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the formula $X/Y=X\bigcap\,Y^{c}$ where $Y^{c}$ the complement of $Y$. Then.

$A\bigcap(B/C)=A\bigcap\,B\,\bigcap\,C^{c}$. $(1)$

Also $(A\bigcap\,B)/(A\bigcap\,C)$=$(A\bigcap\,B)\bigcap[A\bigcap C)^{c}$.
Now the complement of intersection is the union of complements, so the latter

=$(A\bigcap\,B)\bigcap(A^{c}\bigcup\,C^{c})$=$\varnothing\,\bigcup\,A\bigcap\,B\,\bigcap\,C^{c}$

=$A\bigcap\,B\,\bigcap\,C^{c}\,\,\,\,$  $(2)$.

By $(1),(2)$ we get the result!!